# What is wrong with my implementation of the Lisp "cons" function?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, malloc, x86-64

I am trying to make the Lisp function `cons` in x86_84 assembly on MacOS. Below I am trying to make a pair of `2` and `3`, but it is not working; I am getting a segmentation fault.

```
    .global _main
    .extern _malloc
    .text

.macro make_node register 
mov rdi, 8  # 64-bit number
call _malloc  # failed on malloc
mov [rax], \register  # contents of register in address of rax
mov \register, [rax]
.endm

cons:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov r8, [rbp + 16]
    make_node r8
    mov r9, [rbp + 24]
    make_node r9
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

_main:
    push 3
    push 2
    call cons
    add rsp, 16

    # I should now be able to do whatever I want with r8 (2) and r9 (3)

    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall
```

I stepped through it with GDB and I see that it failed on calling `malloc`, but to me, there doesn't seem to be a problem since `malloc` only takes one argument (the number of bytes to allocate) in the `rdi` register.

```
Dump of assembler code for function cons:
   0x0000000100003f48 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000100003f49 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100003f4c <+4>: mov    0x10(%rbp),%r8
   0x0000000100003f50 <+8>: mov    $0x8,%rdi
=> 0x0000000100003f57 <+15>:    callq  0x100003f96
   0x0000000100003f5c <+20>:    mov    %r8,(%rax)
   0x0000000100003f5f <+23>:    mov    (%rax),%r8
   0x0000000100003f62 <+26>:    mov    0x18(%rbp),%r9
   0x0000000100003f66 <+30>:    mov    $0x8,%rdi
   0x0000000100003f6d <+37>:    callq  0x100003f96
   0x0000000100003f72 <+42>:    mov    %r9,(%rax)
   0x0000000100003f75 <+45>:    mov    (%rax),%r9
   0x0000000100003f78 <+48>:    mov    %rbp,%rsp
   0x0000000100003f7b <+51>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000100003f7c <+52>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) ni

Thread 2 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

I am assembling on a Mac like this: `clang -masm=intel cell.asm`.

Does anyone familiar with x86 assembly know the source of my error?

(Also, in case anyone asks, I know that it's important to call `free` after `malloc` but this code is the only code necessary to demonstrate my problem.)

Comment: The likely culprit for that is that at the point before `call _malloc` is done the stack needs to be aligned on a 16 byte boundary. Just before executing the instruction at 0x0000000100003f57 what is the value in RSP?

Comment: My guess is that the HEX value in RSP just before that malloc call ends in a digit other than 0 (but most likely 8). Anything ending in 0 is 16-byte aligned. The 16-byte alignment at the point of a function call is part of the AMD64 System V ABI that MacOS/BSD/Linux adhere to for ABI compliant functions (like any system library or C library function). See section 3.2.2 of the ABI: https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf

Comment: It is really up to your code generator to ensure that the stack is properly aligned in the code generated before AMD64 System V ABI compliant function calls. MacOS is particularly notorious for using instructions that require 16 byte aligned data on the stack.

Comment: Malloc doesn’t preserve the values of r8 and r9.

Comment: I think you intend to put the address of the allocated memory into r8 and r9, not the contents?

Comment: Cons should allocate one space for both values, not two separate spaces.

Comment: Note that the stack alignment problem mentioned by Michael is in main, not in cons.

Comment: FYI, you'd probably have an easier time with GDB or lldb if you set it to use Intel-syntax disassembly, same as your source.  In GDB, that's `set disassembly-flavor intel`, which you can use interactively and/or put in your `~/.gdbinit`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I had no idea there was a settings file for gdb!

Comment: @prl when you said "Cons should allocate one space for both values, not two separate spaces", that makes a lot of sense - but getting a way to have a compound block of memory for the car and the cdr really confuses me. How would I do that? Is there a way to allocate a block of memory and then only access one or the other part of it?

Comment: Yeah, GDB is pretty cool; it can be worth playing around with it some to find a debug setup you're comfortable with that gives you the info you want to see as you single-step.  There are some front-ends for it, and/or mods to it that use its built-in scripting language, to display "windows" of stuff like register values as you step.  (GDB even has a somewhat flaky TUI mode built-in, `layout reg`.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for some GDB tips.)

Comment: @CaspianAhlberg: one block and access parts of it: yes, of course, that's called an array.  `long *p = malloc(16);` and then you can use `p[0]` or `p[1]`.  In asm, `[rax]` or `[rax+8]` for the two qwords.  If that wasn't obvious to you, maybe you need some more practice looking at C programs and how they compile to asm before you're ready to build a compiler.  Or just get in the habit of thinking "how would I do this in C" when you run into an asm question, then you can solve it yourself as you run into problems.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, I fixed my problem! One other question, though: I still don't quite understand the need to do a 16-byte alignment before certain calls. I popped and pushed `rbx` before and after, but how does that align the stack?

Comment: `push` includes `rsp += 8`.  An odd number of pushes in a function realigns the stack after `call` itself pushed a return address.  BTW, don't pop your return address.  Do  a push / call / pop if you need an extra 8 bytes.  I already explained in comments on a previous question of yours why it's super-broken to pop the return address into RBX and then push it, if you aren't saving-restoring the caller's RBX.

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you mean that I should do an `add rsp, 8` before a call and `sub rsp, 8` after the call to `_malloc`?

Comment: No, the opposite.  `sub rsp, 8` (or a dummy push) *before* a call to realign the stack, if the net total number of pushes since the top of the function is even.  Remember the stack grows downward.

Comment: @PeterCordes Got it, thanks.